# Vue.js scoped style is not working on a single component

Tags: css, vue.js

I am using a single component, so deep selector should not be necessary.

Here is the code of the component (ignore the data function being empty, I'm working on design now):

```html
<template>
   <div>
       <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <div class="vue_input col-6">
                <label for="original_word">Original word:</label>   
                <input name='original_word' id='original_word' type="text" v-model="original_word">
            </div>

            <div class="vue_input col-6">
                <label for="translation">Translation:</label>
                <input name="translation" id='translation' type="text" v-model="translation">
            </div>

            <div class="vue_input col-6">
                <label for="hint">Hint:</label>
                <input name="hint" id='hint' type="text" v-model="hint">
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
       data() {
           return {
           }
       },
       name: "example"
   }
</script>
<style scoped>
    .vue_input {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
</style>
```

As you can see I have `.vue_input` classes and one rule of styling for them. Unfortunately, the style is not getting applied. Tried clearing browser's cache/disabling cache. Webpack is compiling properly, because when I add new bootstrap classes it detects such changes and new styling gets applied.

**EDIT:** It's seems that the issue is not exactly with the Vue component. To provide the bigger picture, the component is in Symfony application, which is put into index.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <div id="app">
         <div class="text-center">
            <h3 class="pb-3">Hang your words here</h3>
            <example></example>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>

{% endblock %}
```

It extends the 'base.html.twig', which includes styles and JavaScript, which initializes the Vue componenet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {# Run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`
           and uncomment the following Encore helpers to start using Symfony UX #}
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('global') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app/vue') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Encore entry link `global` includes `global.scss`, where I include bootstrap and then I would include any other styles I would need. Currently it has just one import:

```css
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

If I move the scoped style from Vue component to this global style, then it works:

```css
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

.vue-input {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I think it has something to do with loading order of this import and Vue component's scoped style, but I am not sure what it is exactly.

**EDIT:** Scoped style does not work in the component, even if remove the Bootstrap import.

Comment: Looks like it works fine in Codepen, I added a blue bg to prove the class is being applied. https://codepen.io/JHeth/pen/abyRbVL